# Ordering the third column in excel according to first column (and fill blanks)

Tags: excel

I have three columns, two first columns have identical values, the third one has some values missing (below nr. 2 & 4 are missing).

So how can I "order" these:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 |   |
| 5 | 5 |   |
+---+---+---+
```

To become:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
```

As you can see, the values that are missing are being (i.e. **should be**) filled with zero.
The numbers above are unique (i.e. I can't have two 4's in the same column). So how can I get the same values from Column C to be right next to column B (and then I can fill the empty fields with zero).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have row 1 as headers...

Create a new column D with the formula  in D2=

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,FALSE),0)
```

drag down and then copy/paste special values columns D and delete column C